# Why it's not drawing a rectangle with the mouse on the new transparent form?

Tags: c#, winforms

It's getting to the `F_Paint` event but not to the `F_MouseDown` event.
What I want to be able to draw rectangle on the `F` form.

Maybe since the `F` form is transparent it can't draw on it ? But it's never get to the `F_MouseDown` event I use a break point inside the `F_MouseDown` event.

Not sure why it's not getting to the `MouseDown` event.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Ffmpeg ffmpeg = new Ffmpeg();

        private bool _canDraw;
        private int _startX, _startY;
        private Rectangle _rect;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BackColor = Color.Blue;
            TransparencyKey = BackColor;
            Opacity = 1;
            var f = new HelperForm { Opacity = 0, ShowInTaskbar = false, FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None };
            f.MouseDown += F_MouseDown;
            f.MouseMove += F_MouseMove;
            f.MouseUp += F_MouseUp;
            f.Paint += F_Paint;
            f.Show();
            Visible = false;
            Owner = f;
            Visible = true;
            Move += (o, a) => f.Bounds = Bounds;
            Resize += (o, a) => f.Bounds = Bounds;
            f.Bounds = Bounds;
            ffmpeg.Start(@"d:\ffmpegx86\test.mp4", 24);
        }

        private void F_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //Create a new 'pen' to draw our rectangle with, give it the color red and a width of 2
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
            {
                //Draw the rectangle on our form with the pen
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _rect);
            }
        }

        private void F_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //The system is no longer allowed to draw rectangles
            _canDraw = false;
        }

        private void F_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //If we are not allowed to draw, simply return and disregard the rest of the code
            if (!_canDraw) return;

            //The x-value of our rectangle should be the minimum between the start x-value and the current x-position
            int x = Math.Min(_startX, e.X);
            //The y-value of our rectangle should also be the minimum between the start y-value and current y-value
            int y = Math.Min(_startY, e.Y);

            //The width of our rectangle should be the maximum between the start x-position and current x-position minus
            //the minimum of start x-position and current x-position
            int width = Math.Max(_startX, e.X) - Math.Min(_startX, e.X);

            //For the hight value, it's basically the same thing as above, but now with the y-values:
            int height = Math.Max(_startY, e.Y) - Math.Min(_startY, e.Y);
            _rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            //Refresh the form and draw the rectangle
            Refresh();
        }

        private void F_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //The system is now allowed to draw rectangles
            _canDraw = true;
            //Initialize and keep track of the start position
            _startX = e.X;
            _startY = e.Y;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            ffmpeg.Close();
        }
    }

    class HelperForm : Form
    {
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x80;
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
                return cp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're setting the `Opacity` to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several reasons preventing the rectangle from being drawn and firing mouse events. First, you're setting the `Opacity` to `0`; this means whatever you try to draw could never be visible. Instead, you should set the `TransparencyKey` to the color in `BackColor`:

```
f.TransparencyKey = f.BackColor;
```

Then, you're trying to draw a rectangle using the object `_rect` which was never initialized; therefore the rectangle you're trying to draw will be drawn with the size of 0 width and 0 height which means it won't be drawn, so, during your initialization, you should give a default value for `_rect` e.g:

```
_rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.Size);
```

The drawn rectangle should be visible by now; however, the events won't fire because you're reversing form ownership, so, instead of

```
Owner = f;
```

Use:

```
f.Owner = this;
```